# Javascript overwrite the scope of a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I stumbled into this problem recently and after a while of reading around I couldn't find an answer that satisfies this use case in particular.

I am trying to achieve the following behaviour in javascript

```
// Lets assume we have some variable defined in global scope
var a = {val: 0} 

// What I want here is a function that sets a.val = newVal
// and then calls the callback. 
var start = function(newVal, cb) {
  ???
}

// such that
start(1, function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(a.val) // 1
  }, 1000)
})

// and
start(2,function () {
  console.log(a.val) // 2
})

// but in the original scope
console.log(a.val) // 0
```

In other words i am looking for a way to "wrap" a callback in a different global scope. I am aware that you can do something similar passing an environment around or using this; but such methods always force the callback functions to refer to the environment explicitly, turning the callback code into something like

```
start(2,function () {
  console.log(env.a.val) // 2
})
```

I am specifically looking for a solution that preserves the possibility to use the global reference directly from within the callback of start.

Feel free to use any ES6/ES7 feature that can somehow be shimmed in or is compatible with node, this is not meant for production code just a fun exercise.

EDIT:
I will explain the general problem since many people suggested this solution might not be what I am actually looking for.

I recently learned about STM (https://wiki.haskell.org/Software_transactional_memory)
and wanted to play around with a similar idea in js. 
Of course js runs on a single thread but the idea was to provide the same level of isolation to different callbacks running in atomic blocks.

The user has some kind of shared transactional variable. Operations on this
variable must be wrapped in atomically blocks. What happens under the hood is that operations in the atomically block are not performed on the actual TVar but on some MockTVar which simply records all the reads and writes in a log.
When you call the done the log is checked to see if the operations performed are consistent with the current state of the TVars; if it is the updates now performed on the actual TVars and we are done (this is called a commit). If it is not the log is discarded and the callback is run again. This is a small example of the code

```
var x = new TVar(2)

// this is process a
process.nextTick(function() {
  atomically(x, function(x, done) {
    a = x.readTVar()

    setTimeout(function() {
      x.writeTVar(a+1)
      console.log('Process a increased, x = ', x.readTVar())
      done()
    }, 2000)
  })
})

// this is process b
process.nextTick(function() {
  atomically(x, function(x, done) {
    var a = x.readTVar()
    x.writeTVar(a+1)
    console.log('Process b increased, x = ', x.readTVar())
    done()
 })
```

})

In this example process a will try to commit but since process b changed the value of x (and committed that change before a) the commit will fail and the callback will run once more.

As you can see I am returning the mockTVars in the callback, but i find this a bit ugly for two reasons: 
1) If you want to lock more than one variable (and you generally do) i have no choice but to return an array of mockTVars forcing the user to extract them one by one if he wants to use them cleanly. 
2) It is up to the user to make sure that the name of the mockTVar which is passed to the callback matches the name of the actual TVar if he wants to be able to reason about whats happening without losing his mind. What I mean is that in this line

```
atomically(x, function(x, done) {..})
```

It is up to the user to use the same name to refer both to the actual TVar and the mocked TVar (the name is x in this example).

I hope this explanation is helpful. Thanks to everybody that took the time to help me out

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? make sure this isn't an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I think that this type of thing is only possible in command lisp with macros or in Emacs lisp with dynamic variables.

Comment: You're essentially asking how you can use a single variable to store multiple values, which isn't possible.

Comment: You're also completing missing one of the main features of a callback, which is to pass values through.  Why do you need to change a.val = bleh when you could just pass bleh directly to the callback?

Comment: Is it important to stay using `a` variable? Can we change it to `this` or smth else? It gives opportunities to use function context (this) of the function-fabric pattern.

Comment: There is no case where `a.val` in one scope shows one value and `a.val` in another scope shows another value and it's the same `a` in both places.  If you want to make a copy of the variable `a` and create that copy in a lower scope, then you can freely refer to `a` and it will modify the copy, not the global.  But that's it.  There is no magic ES6 feature here to the rescue.  What you really need to do is to describe your REAL problem so we can help you solve that rather than this non-existent solution you asked for to some problem you haven't describe.

Comment: The XY problem issue explains that you should share your actual problem, not just issues you had with your attempted solution.  Then and only then, we can offer you the full toolkit of ways to solve your real problem.  And, this is even worse when  your attempted solution isn't possible.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve with that?, the objects in Javascript are passed by reference, what means that the value of a.val will be the last assign, in your example you want a copy o object "a" in each function where this is called?.

Answer (score 1):

I still wish you would describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, but here's one idea, that makes a copy of the global object, passes it to the callback and the callback can use the same name as the global and then it will "override" access to the global for that scope only.

```js
    var a = {val: 0, otherVal: "hello"} ;
    
    function start(newVal, cb) {
        var copy = {};
        Object.assign(copy, a);
        copy.val = newVal;
        cb(copy);
    }
    
    log("Before start, a.val = " + a.val);
    start(1, function(a) {
       // locally scoped copy of "a" here that is different than the global "a"
       log("Beginning of start, a.val = " + a.val) // 1
       a.val = 2;
       log("End of start, a.val = " + a.val) // 2
    });

    log("After start, a.val = " + a.val);
    
    function log(x) {
        document.write(x + "<br>");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am actually looking for, I am specifically trying to avoid passing the variable in the callback. I actually found a veeeery ugly solution which consists of setting the value on a, then calling `toString()` on the callback and then evalling it in the start function. This basically makes it work as if the callback was defined inside the start function giving it the desired scope. This works but it feels a bit like the cure is worst than the disease in the first place :P

Comment: @user2512250 - You can't change the definition of `a` in a scope without modifying `a` or defining a new one in the local scope.  Those are just the rules of Javascript.  If you're ruling out both of these options, then it's not clear what you're asking for then.  Those are your options outside of some really gross hack like trying to dynamically modify code.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. The issue I have with the solution I posted is more about calling `toString` on a function, and then calling eval on that string, than about touching the value of `a`. What I am trying to rule out is the need to pass the modified value in the callback.

Comment: @nazrhom - Yeah, dynamically modifying code is a horrible solution.  I agree.   You've so restricted the tools available to solve this problem that I don't think there are any other solutions.  Javascript does not allow you to modify the scope of a function from outside the function unless it's an inline function in which case the parent can redefine variable names in the parent scope.  Anything else can't be done besides passing it in or modifying the global.  Function scopes are private.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean, there is ultimately no way around this. As a little follow-up: another solution I was considering to use `cb.call()` to set the new value for `a` on the `this` of the callback. Then in the code of the callback, you can simply refer to this.a.val. The benefit here is to avoid having to explicitly pass the value(s) to the callback for the reasons mentioned in the edit of my question. Is there anything else I could consider to achieve the same benefit?

Comment: @nazrhom - Yes, that can work fine.  I don't understand what the reluctance is to passing an argument to the function - that's how pretty much ALL callbacks work.  Your `this.a` solution does not redefine the symbol `a` like your question asked - it requires the writer of the function to refer to the data differently.